# Install ODBC Driver under Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, mysql, netbeans, iodbc

I have the latest version of `MySQL` and `NetBeans` installed on my system. I also have the `iODBC` driver manager installed. I need help with installing an `ODBC driver` and creating a `DSN` for my JSP project. I know how to create and configure a DSN under Windows. But I can't figure out how to do this under Ubuntu. Neither am I able to install an `ODBC driver`. How to do these?

Comment: Why would you want an ODBC for a database you can interact with directly and natively? Use [Connector/J](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connector-j.html) for a direct connection. That would be better in every single way.

Comment: @Oli: How do I do that? Please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that it was easier to use `MySQL Connector/J` for the connection as @Oli described.